# To evaluate the given integral

Tags: definite-integrals

If $0<a<1$ and $ A = \int_{0}^a \cos^{-1}x~\mathrm dx $, then $$\int_{-a}^a(\cos^{-1}x -\sin^{-1}\sqrt {1-x^2})~\mathrm dx =\pi a -\lambda A $$
Then find the value of $\lambda$

My doubt :

$\sin^{-1}\sqrt {1-x^2}=\cos^{-1}x $ if we write this then the value of requires integral will zero.

$\pi a-\lambda A =0 $.

Can anyone explain how to find the value of $\lambda$?

Comment: your condition on $a$ is wrong. It's not enough that a>0.

Comment: @FDP can you expain it further

Comment: where is defined $\cos^{-1}x$?

Comment: @FDP its understood the value of $a \in [-1,1]$

Comment: By the way, what is the parity of $\cos^{-1}x$?

Comment: @FDP sorry i didnt get you

Comment: If f is even what can you say about $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx$ if you know the value of $\int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$? ($f$ is defined on $[-a,a]$)

Comment: @FDP it will be two times of that value